# Can the Extension Library be used without having to use OneUI (specifically Dojo Form Controls)?

Tags: css, dojo, xpages, xpages-extlib

I am trying to use some of the ExtLib controls (specifically the Dojo Form Controls) in an application that doesn't use OneUI, thus, when opening the app in the browser, the Dojo controls are not rendered properly

My question is:

- Do you have to use OneUI in combination with ExtLib in order to have the Dojo Form Controls rendered properly?
- If you can use ExtLib without OneUI, how do I pull in the needed .css files for the Dojo Form controls?

Any help in this matter would be highly appreciates.

Thank you.

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'd like to thank everyone who took a look into this issue and responded to my question.

After doing some extensive research and trial and error, I am 99.9% convinced that you **can't use the Dojo List Text Box from the extension library without OneUI.**

I was under the impression that the Dojo List Text Box is using the dojox.form.ListInput library, but that doesn't seem to be the case. It seems that one of the dijit.form elements (dijit.form.textbox?) is being used in combination with .css files to make it look the way it does when using the extension library (please correct me if I am wrong).

That being said, I came up with my own solution, recreating the functionality of the ExtLib Dojo List Text Box, by using a repeat control, computed field and css. If anyone is interested, I will post a detailed description of my solution on my blog [xpagesandme.wordpress.com](http://xpagesandme.wordpress.com).

Thank you.

Comment: Please add a short outline of the solution here as well, as link-only answers are not preferred here.

Comment: Hello Philip, I added a few more details to my answer. However, as I only have a reputation of 6, I can't add any images, etc. and have to refer to my blog link.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the extension library can be used without oneUI, however many of the controls, especially the dojo controls expect to have some dojo theme or dojo css files.  One link you might reference is the dojo toolkit page based on themes.  Hopefully this will help you get an idea of what you need to have CSS-wise on your page to make the dijits render correctly.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/themes.html

Comment: Hello Toby,

thank you for your response. I tried to reference the ListInput.css in the dojox/form/resources folder to apply the style to the "Dojo List Text Box" control from the ExtLib. Though it did apply some styles, it doesn't look anything like as if you were to use it in combination with OneUI. Am I missing something? I am using the tundra dojo theme btw.

Answer (score 0):

The App Layout Control, Form Table, and Data View all require the IBM One UI theme (or the bootstrap4xpages project).

Are you using your Dojo form controls with any of those?

Howard

Comment: Hello Howard, thank you for your response. No, I just wanted to use Dojo List Text Box from the extension library, but it is not rendered properly if you don't use OneUI. Thus I created something similar myself, using repeat control. I'll post how I did it on my blog [xpages and me](http://xpagesandme.wordpress.com) so, others can use it as well.